# Как перенести код с VB 6 на VB 2010

Tags: vb6, vb.net

Как переписать код с vb6 на vb 2010?

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow2(ppDisp As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 
Dim frmWB As Form1 
Set frmWB = New Form1 
Set ppDisp = frmWB.WebBrowser1.Object 
frmWB.Visible = True 
Set frmWB = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря студии нет под руками. Но могу предположить, что у вас нет свойства .Object.

А что вы хотите с эти делать? 
Вам вообще не нужна эта функция. Создайте себе экземпляр веб-браузера... ну что-то типа:

```
Dim myWebBrowser As New WebBrowser()
```

Там, где вам нужно и работайте с ним - судя по коду, вам не нужно визуальное отображение контрола на экране.

Ну или юзайте что-то типа HTTPClient (не помню как называется, но там в System.net много чего есть).